# how to get authorization from a http request using vba

Tags: excel, vba

i have to send a HTTP post request to a web page using vba. i have successfully done that with the below code. the problem i am facing is that the api key (authorization) is changing every time i log into that page. so it can not be a constant. can i pull the authorization key(encrypted) by any method and set the authorization from requestHeaders as a variable to send my HTTP post Request?

```
 Sub WEBAPP()

 Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, myurl As String
 myurl = "www.abc.com"


 xmlhttp.Open "post", myurl, False
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "authorization", "myEncryptedUsernameAndPassword" 'i need to set this as my variable
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
 xmlhttp.send "name=jack&company=google"

 MsgBox (xmlhttp.responseText)

 End Sub
```

Comment: its up to the service you are pulling from. if they have an endpoint exposed upon where to get a fresh authorization key, then you can do that. you would of course, need some login creds to get that auth key. once you get the auth key you can pass into your existing call very variable

Comment: i have the login creds. i am talking about sending the HTTP  post request to a web page which is already loged in. i can see the encrypted authorization credentials in the crome developer tools, ->network->XHR-> requestheaders->authorization. the problem is due to its changing nature, i need to go to the said path and copy paste it to my code each time i log in.(it will stay same until i log out of the page)

Comment: A public API that constantly changes its auth details and doesn't provide ways to obtain said details won't be around for long. Did you check the documentation?